# MySQL query for on user to list of users

Tags: mysql, sql

My message system is based on message, threads, and participant

- a message created by a user is linked to a thread
- two participants (or more) are linked to a thread
- each participant is linked to one user

I got this request. It give me the number of message a user has received (= number of message where the user is not the creator)

I count all messages created in a list of threads where the user is not the creator.
I got the list of threads by find all thread_id where my user participant is linked

```
SELECT COUNT(m.id) 
FROM message m 
INNER JOIN message_thread t ON m.thread_id = t.id 
WHERE m.created_by_id != :userId 
AND t.id IN (
    SELECT t2.id
    FROM message_thread t2 
    INNER JOIN message_participants p ON p.thread_id = t2.id 
    WHERE p.user_id = :userId
)
```

So that is for one uniq user.

```
+-------------+
| count(m.id) |
+-------------+
| 7           |
+-------------+
```

I'm trying to do the same, but with severals users, and get for each of them, the number of message they received

```
+---------+-------------+
| User id | count(m.id) |
+---------+-------------+
| 12645   | 1           |
| 985     | 5           |
| 8956    | 15          |
| 37856   | 2           |
+---------+-------------+
```

I tried to do that with more JOIN instead of `t.id IN (` and group by the result, but without success...

Comment: Where is the list of users that you want to get message counts for stored?

Comment: It will be a parameter.
Like  
```
user_id IN (:userIds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is a brute force method, where you bring in all the users you care about and use that information for the processing:

```
SELECT u.userid, COUNT(m.id) 
FROM message m INNER JOIN
     message_thread t
     ON m.thread_id = t.id CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT 12645 as userid UNION ALL
      SELECT 985 UNION ALL
      SELECT 8956 UNION ALL
      SELECT 37856
     ) u    
WHERE m.created_by_id <> u.userId AND
      t.id IN (SELECT t2.id
               FROM message_thread t2 INNER JOIN
                    message_participants p
                    ON p.thread_id = t2.id 
               WHERE p.user_id = u.userId
              )
GROUP BY u.userId;
```

If you wanted to do this for all users, I would recommend a different approach:  count all the messages a user participates in and subtract out the ones where s/he is the creator:

```
SELECT p.userid,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE m.created_by_id <> p.userId THEN m.id END) as numMessages
FROM message m INNER JOIN
     message_thread t
     ON m.thread_id = t.id INNER JOIN
     message_participants p
     ON p.thread_id = t.id 
GROUP BY p.userid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a group by

```
SELECT message_thread.your_user_id COUNT(m.id) 
FROM message m 
INNER JOIN message_thread t ON m.thread_id = t.id 
WHERE m.created_by_id != :userId 
AND t.id IN (
    SELECT t2.id
    FROM message_thread t2 
    INNER JOIN message_participants p ON p.thread_id = t2.id 
)
group by message_thread.your_user_id
```